# How to strip HTML from a text column in Azure ML Execute Python Script step

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

If I have a column of data of type string in an incoming Azure ML dataset that contains HTML tags screwing up my results, how can I remove those tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
  dataframe1[1] = dataframe1['text'].str.replace('<[^<]+?>', ' ', case=False)
  return dataframe1,
```

Remember to precede the `Execute Python Script` step with `Clean Missing Data` step and change the action to remove the entire row (if appropriate). This is important because the `Execute Python Script` step cannot return an empty `dataframe`. Only you know your data, in this case.

Let me also point out that the `Preprocessing Text` step allows you to apply a Regular Expression. That is another alternative that might be right for your situation.